# How to close a page in Xamarin Prism?

Tags: xamarin, prism

I have page A and with a button, I go to page B

Now I want to close page B and "page A" appear
(But I don't want to call her again, since the page To make assessments if there is internet, ping the Server, etc. and I don't want to make these checks again.

That is why I want page A to appear once I have closed page B

(As if it were a kind of PopUp (But I don't want to use PopUp because of the type of page and data on page B)

Thank you.

Comment: Could you share the code related to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to `PageB` from `PageA` with:

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("PageB");
```

Then you can go back with :

```
NavigationService.GoBackAsync();
```

If you go to `PageB` from `PageA` with Model style(like `PopUp` as you mentioned in the question):

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("PageB", useModalNavigation: true);
```

You can use below codes to go back:

```
NavigationService.GoBackAsync(useModalNavigation: true);
```

> But I don't want to call her again

To achieve that, you can make the button in `Page1` not visible after `Page1` appear again.